# OOP login authentication php code

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, singleton

I am getting an error which is like this ---------- Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\index.php on line 7

code is written below

```
 <?php

class DB{

private static $_instance = NULL;

private $_pdo , $_query , $_error = false, $_results, $_count = 0;

    public function __construct(){

        try{
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/dbname'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));

            echo'connected';
        }

        catch(PDOException $e){

            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance(){

        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){

            self::$_instance = new DB;

        }

        else{

            return self::$_instance;
        }

    }

    public function sqlQuery($query){

        $this->_error = false;

        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->query($query)){
            echo'ok';
        }
    }



}
?>﻿
```

And here is the index page

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = DB::getInstance();

$user -> query('SELECT * FROM user');

?>
```

Comment: try changing ```$this->_pdo``` to ```$this->$_pdo```

Comment: It's not helping.

Comment: @AndrewDonovan what? So in which unknown PHP version are you?

Comment: @NikhilSindhu don't use Singleton for database connection. Learn about dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getInstance()` in your code doesn't return an instance of `DB` the first time you call `getInstance()`.

Edit the method to:

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if (!isset(self::$_instance))
    {
        self::$_instance = new DB;
    }

    return self::$_instance;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Why your `$user` equals to `null` after this line: `$user = DB::getInstance();`?

Look into your realisation of `getInstance()`. What happens when you execute it the first time:

```
public static function getInstance(){
    // At first call self::$_instance equals to null,
    // therefore !isset(self::$_instance) is true
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        // So, at first call, this branch executes.
        self::$_instance = new DB;
        // What do we return at first call? 
        // Nothing, because there is no "return" statement here.
    }

    else{
        // So, this branch will be executed at second and next calls.
        // Therefore only after the first call it will return a DB instance
        return self::$_instance;
    }

}
```

How to write `getInstance()` correctly? Just remove `else` from this code like in my answer above.

Comment: getInstance() method is creating new object in first time and assigning it to private property $_instance and as object is created constructor is assigning PDO to $_pdo. Later I am using $_pdo to execute method query('SELECT * FROM user') in my public method sqlQuery().

Comment: In result of your code `$user = DB::getInstance();` you have `$user` equals to null. I recommend you to try my advice.

Comment: Ok sir, will you please help me to edit it so it can work properly. And one more thing can I know the reason why I am getting null.